# How to make addValueChangeHandler act just like addChangeHandler

Tags: java, gwt, event-handling

I made a wrap widget that implements interface HasChangeHandlers

But i just can't fit events to each other.

```
public HandlerRegistration addChangeHandler( final ChangeHandler handler ) {
    HandlerRegistration registration1 = dateFrom.addValueChangeHandler( handler );// Compile error

    HandlerRegistration registration2 = dateTo.addValueChangeHandler( new ValueChangeHandler<Date>() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange( ValueChangeEvent<Date> dateValueChangeEvent ) {
              //have to fire handler ??
        }
    } );

    return null; // what i should return here?
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return the handler of the member object that you want the event to be associated to. For example I have a textbox+label widget and I couldnt create @UiHandler event on it from somewhere because it is not standard so what i did was:

```
public class TextBoxAndLabel implements HasKeyUpHandlers {

private TextBox myTextBox;
private Label myLabel;


    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addKeyUpHandler(KeyUpHandler keyUpHandler) {
        return myTextBox.addKeyUpHandler(keyUpHandler);
    }

}
```

and now I can implement

```
@UiHandler("myClassObject")
```

Answer (score 1):

A ChangeHandler is not a ValueChangeHandler.  You have to make another wrapper class which implements ValueChangeHandler and takes a ChangeHandler as an instance variable.  You can then write...

`HandlerRegistration registration1 = dateFrom.addValueChangeHandler(new ChangeHandlerWrapper(handler));`

Where ChangeHandlerWrapper is a class that implements ValueChangeHandler.  For example,

```
class ChangeHandlerWrapper<T> implements ValueChangeHandler<Date>
{
   private ChangeHandler handler;

   public void onValueChange( ValueChangeEvent<T> changeEvent) {
      handler.onChange(null);
   }
}
```

Of course, this assumes that you don't need the actual event in your handler.  If you do then things will get more complicated.